# Adding to a Database - C# with Access

Tags: c#, ms-access, sql-insert

Below is the code I'm using to connect to an Access Database.
I'm trying to insert the data (which is a form the user fills in). But always the exception is caught and no data gets inserted.

I've double checked the variable names for spelling errors,they are all correct.

```
private void addConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\hospitalApplication\HealthCare.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";

        String name = typedName.Text;
        String addr = typedAddr.Text;
        String DOB = typedDOB.Text;
        String phone = typedPhone.Text;
        String emergency = typedEmergency.Text;
        String dateOfReg = typedDateReg.Text;
        String patientstatus = typedStatus.Text;
        String bedNo = typedBed.Text;
        String blood = typedBlood.Text;
        String visit = typedVisit.Text;
        String diagnosis = typedDiagnosis.Text;
        String doctorID = typedDoctor.Text;


        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into Patients (Full Name, Address,Date of Birth,Phone No,Emergency Contact,Date of Registration,Patient Status,bedID,Blood Type,Date of Visit,Diagnosis,doctorID) Values(@name, @addr,@DOB,@phone,@emergency,@dateOfReg,@patientstatus,@bedNo,@blood,@visit,@diagnosis,@doctorID)", conn);
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        conn.Open();

        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@addr", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = addr;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DOB;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@phone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = phone;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@emergency", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = emergency;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateOfReg", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = dateOfReg;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@patientstatus", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = patientstatus;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@bedNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = bedNo;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@blood", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = blood;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@visit", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = visit;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@diagnosis", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = diagnosis;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@doctorID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = doctorID;

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Added");
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Source);
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
        }
```

Comment: What's the exception?  The first step in correcting an error is *reading* the error message.

Comment: SQL is not going to like those spaces in the column names

Answer (score 3):

Your SQL in invalid.  The spaces are confusing the query parser.

The best approach is to not use spaces in your table/column names.  But if you must, then you'll need to enclose them in brackets to tell the query parser that both words identify one item.  Something like this:

```
INSERT into Patients ([Full Name], ...
```

Do this for any table/column name which includes either spaces or reserved words.  (You can do this for all of the table/column names if you'd like.)